# Why is AngularDart 5.0.0 router calling NgOnInit() twice?

Tags: angular-dart

I am building an AngularDart 5.0.0 app with a "users" page:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'users-page',
  directives: const [coreDirectives],
  pipes: [COMMON_PIPES],
  templateUrl: 'users_page_component.html',
  styleUrls: const [
    'users_page_component.css',
  ],
)
class UsersPageComponent extends OnInit {
  ngOnInit() async {
    print("ngOnInit() ${this.hashCode}");
  }
}
```

I set up a route to this page in my AppComponent and define the route:

```
static final routes = [
   new RouteDefinition(
      routePath: usersRoutePath,
      component: users.UsersPageComponentNgFactory),
];

<router-outlet [routes]="AppComponent.routes"></router-outlet>
```

with the route defined outside the class:

```
final usersRoutePath = new RoutePath(
  path: 'users',
  parent: appRoutePath,
  useAsDefault: true,
);
```

When the user taps a button, I call `_router.navigate()`:

```
_router.navigate(usersRoutePath.toUrl(parameters: params));
```

When I tap the button, two calls are made to `NgOnInit()`:

```
ngOnInit() 80777801
ngOnInit() 464932208
```

I have triple-checked that `.navigate()` is only being called once.

This is a problem because I need to make a network call when the User page loads and would like to avoid making it twice in a row.

Is this a bug? How can I prevent multiple UsersPage components from being created?

Comment: Is this your only route registered to that router outlet? Or does your AppComponent implement CanReuse? It's possible the UsersPageComponent is created while resolving the route, but then recreated if it's parent isn't reusable. This is a known issue.

Comment: The route is registered to the router outlet. AppComponent does not implement CanReuse. I can try that.

Comment: Just to update this: The best solution right now is to for UsersPageComponent to implement OnActivate instead of OnInit

Comment: That is correct. The router may create/destroy components while resolving routes, and in some cases cache a component for reuse when deactivated. It's always best to use the router lifecycle interfaces (OnActivate/OnDeactivate) for routed components. In your case, I'm guessing you were navigating between routes nested under AppComponent. If the parent component isn't reusable, the child route will be created during resolution, but then destroyed and recreated again during activation when the parent is not reused.